# Flash AS2 Loop Error

Tags: xml, flash, twitter, actionscript-2

this is pulling data from Twitter Feed with xml, it's working good but i can't pull the first data?

> trace(wordList[0]) is always undefined

If i want to add the date i am writing this:

```
childItems[i].childNodes[0].firstChild.nodeValue
```

how can push this to the array?

```
var wordList:Array = new Array();

var curIndex:Number = 0;

var reviews_xml:XML = new XML();
reviews_xml.ignoreWhite = true;
reviews_xml.onLoad = function (success:Boolean):Void {
    if (success) {
        var childItems:Array = reviews_xml.firstChild.childNodes;

        for (var i:Number = 0; i < childItems.length; i++) {
            wordList.push(childItems[i].childNodes[2].firstChild.nodeValue);
        }
        resimAlanim.loadMovie(childItems[0].childNodes[9].childNodes[5].firstChild.nodeValue);

    } else {
        trace("yüklenemedi");
    }
}


setInterval( showNextText, 3000 );

function showNextText()
{
    curIndex++;
    renderText(curIndex);
     if((curIndex )== wordList.length){
         curIndex = 0;
         renderText(curIndex);
     };
}

function renderText( index:Number )
{
    text_mc.text = wordList[index];
    trace(index);
}

reviews_xml.load("https://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline.xml?include_entities=false&include_rts=true&screen_name=twitter&count=5");

renderText(curIndex);
stop();
```

Comment: Put break points in there, run it in the debugger, and see what's going awry. There's no way to know without seeing your XML.

Comment: Hi Amy,i am adding my xml urk, and how can i debug the code? i haven't done that before?

this is my xml url:
https://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline.xml?include_entities=false&include_rts=true&screen_name=twitter&count=5

Comment: Press Ctrl-Shift-Enter. The file will sort of half-way launch, and you should go where the code above is and click on the narrow gray bar to the left of where the line numbers can go. You'll see a red dot there, which is your breakpoint. When it gets to the breakpoint, go to the tab that shows your local variables or dig through the object tree to see what the values of things are.

Answer (score 0):

```
reviews_xml.firstChild.childNodes
```

will probably contain 
`<created_at />` to  `<retweeted />`

You can check this by looking in the debugger or doing a trace statement.
created_at has only one childNode (in the as2 version of XML handling, there's an implicit childNode around that nodeValue).

So

```
childItems[i].childNodes[2].firstChild.nodeValue
```

will be null, since there is no second child node on that node.

Note that one of the reasons AS3 was created is because it would not fail silently on that line, but instead give you an error. Silent failure is **not** your friend.

There's a second possibility, which is that the problem is that your XML hasn't loaded before you're trying to access it. I don't see anything in your code that waits for the xml load for sure before trying to read the values from the array.